# Exploratory PCA in Julia

Tags: julia, pca

I try to understand how to perform a simple, exploratory PCA in Julia using the package MultivariateStats.jl.

For instance, in R, one may do the following:

```r
library(FactoMineR)
data(iris)

## PCA model:
res_pca <- PCA(iris, quali.sup = 5, graph = FALSE)
## Retrieve coordinates of individuals on all 4 PCs:
res_pca$ind$coord
## Simple plots:
plot(res_pca, choix = "ind", habillage = 5)
plot(res_pca, choix = "var")
```

I don't manage to get any equivalent of these very basic operations in Julia (using "native" functions from MultivariateStats.jl, I mean). Let's begin with:

```
using MultivariateStats
using RDatasets

iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

## PCA model:
M = fit(PCA, Array(iris[:, 1:4]); pratio=1, maxoutdim=4)
```

Once I get the PCA "model" `M`, how can I retrieve easily the individuals coordinates? How can I display easily the correlation circle, etc.?

As I understand it, PCA is implemented in Julia as a "model" from a quasi machine learning perspective, and offers basically no way to display easily all usual graphs, statistics and insights one usually need in exploratory PCA? (I mean, cos², contributions, etc.)

Is there any other Julia package more oriented towards exploratory multivariate analysis which could offer a rough equivalent of famous R packages such as FactoMineR or ade4?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a related discussion here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pca-output/22687

Comment: Thanks! This thread was helpful. But it seems to confirm that PCA-related stuff in the Julia ecosystem is indeed in a very rudimentary state as of today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so firstly you're putting the data in with the wrong orientation. As you can see from the [docs](https://multivariatestatsjl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pca.html?highlight=pca#fit)

> **fit(PCA, X; ...)**
> Perform PCA over the data given in a matrix X. Each column of X is an observation.

you need observations as columns and variables as rows. This may seem confusing given that we normally think of variables as columns, but it makes a bit more sense in the context of the underlying linear algebra. So to get that right, let's start with:

```
using MultivariateStats, Statistics
using RDatasets: dataset

iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")
iris_matrix = Array(iris[:, 1:4])'

## PCA model:
M = fit(PCA, iris_matrix; pratio=1, maxoutdim=4)
```

As you've noticed, this returns an object of type `PCA`. As it turns out, the available methods for this type are well described in the [documentation](https://multivariatestatsjl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pca.html):

> **Properties**
>
> Let M be an instance of PCA, d be the dimension of observations, and p be the output dimension (i.e the dimension of the principal subspace)
>
> **indim(M)**
> Get the input dimension d, i.e the dimension of the observation space.
>
> **outdim(M)**
> Get the output dimension p, i.e the dimension of the principal subspace.
>
> **mean(M)**
> Get the mean vector (of length d).
>
> **projection(M)**
> Get the projection matrix (of size (d, p)). Each column of the projection matrix corresponds to a principal component.
>
> The principal components are arranged in descending order of the corresponding variances.
>
> **principalvars(M)**
> The variances of principal components.
>
> **tprincipalvar(M)**
> The total variance of principal components, which is equal to sum(principalvars(M)).
>
> **tresidualvar(M)**
> The total residual variance.
>
> **tvar(M)**
> The total observation variance, which is equal to tprincipalvar(M) + tresidualvar(M).
>
> **principalratio(M)**
> The ratio of variance preserved in the principal subspace, which is equal to tprincipalvar(M) / tvar(M).

but if you didn't know that or had trouble finding the docs, you could get a full list of all the available methods (as for *any* type in Julia) by using the `methodswith` function -- in this case specifically `methodswith(PCA)`.

Key among these is `projection`, which gives us the actual projection matrix:

```
julia> proj = projection(M)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 -0.361387    0.656589  -0.58203     0.315487
  0.0845225   0.730161   0.597911   -0.319723
 -0.856671   -0.173373   0.0762361  -0.479839
 -0.358289   -0.075481   0.545831    0.753657
```

As the documentation told us

> each column of the projection matrix corresponds to a principal component

so `proj[:,1]` contains the weights / "loadings" for PC1, `proj[:,2]` contains the loadings for PC2, etc.

Since you asked about contributions, by which I am guessing you mean the contributions of each principal component towards explaining the total variance, the docs tell us you can get that with `principalvars`:

```
julia> principalvars(M)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 4.2282417060348605
 0.24267074792863352
 0.07820950004291898
 0.023835092973449976
```

so PC1 is really doing most of the heavy lifting here. Or if you prefer that in terms of percent of the total variance explained by each component, then:

```
julia> principalvars(M) ./ tvar(M) * 100
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 92.46187232017269
  5.306648311706788
  1.7102609807929683
  0.5212183873275495
```

Looking ahead to the "transformation" section of the same docs

> **Transformation and Construction**
>
> Given a PCA model M, one can use it to transform observations into principal components, as
>
> = ᵀ ( - )
>
> or use it to reconstruct (approximately) the observations from principal components, as
>
> ̃ =   +
>
> Here,  is the projection matrix.
>
> The package provides methods to do so:
>
> **transform(M, x)**
> Transform observations x into principal components.
>
> Here, x can be either a vector of length d or a matrix where each column is an observation.
>
> **reconstruct(M, y)**
> Approximately reconstruct observations from the principal components given in y.
>
> Here, y can be either a vector of length p or a matrix where each column gives the principal components for an observation.

we can see that the way to apply this transformation to our data is

```
iris_transformed = transform(M, iris_matrix)
```

or if you want to do the linear algebra yourself

```
iris_transformed = projection(M)' * (iris_matrix .- mean(M))
```

Then once we have the transformed data, we could, say, plot the first two principal components against each other with

```
using Plots
h = plot(iris_transformed[1,:], iris_transformed[2,:], seriestype=:scatter, label="")
plot!(xlabel="PC1", ylabel="PC2", framestyle=:box) # A few formatting options
```

[image: PCA of the Iris dataset, plotting PC1 vs PC2]

Finally, if you want to add arrows for the different variables, it turns out we already have everything we need in `projection(M)`, which we have already stored as `proj`

```
for i=1:4; plot!([0,proj[i,1]], [0,proj[i,2]], arrow=true, label=names(iris)[i], legend=:bottomleft); end
display(h)
```

[image: PCA plot showing vectors for each variable]

Edit: I should probably also mention that while there isn't (yet) a StatsPlots recipe for the PCA type, there is one for MDS, so you can in this case obtain an equivalent plot as above by writing simply

```
M = fit(MDS, iris_matrix; distances=false)
using StatsPlots
plot(M)
```

(PCA and MDS being equivalent for the case as here where the distance metric is euclidean distance in the original (i.e., high-dimensional) vector space)